# Get the last part of an url in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using the following URL example, how would I get the obtain the username from it?

http://www.mysite.com/username_here801

A regex solution would be cool.

The following sample only gets the domain name:

```
  var url = $(location).attr('href');

  alert(get_domain(url));

  function get_domain(url) {
    return url.match(/http:\/\/.*?\//);
  }
```

jQuery solutions are also acceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/username_here801";    
var username = url.match(/username_(.+)/)[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LHFd/

To always return the text directly after the slash that follows the .com you can do this:

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/username_here801";
var urlsplit = url.split("/");
var username = urlsplit[3];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LHFd/2/

Comment: K. username_ was just an example, not a pattern. The pattern I am trying to match is anything after the first forward slash following the domain extension .com

Comment: @Vini The second part of my answer using split should work for you then.

Answer (score 4):

You can access it with `document.location.pathname`

Comment: OP's probably asking how to extract the last portion from the _supplied_ URL.

Answer (score 1):

If a RegEx solution is acceptable, you could try:

```
function get_path(url) {
    // following regex extracts the path from URL
    return url.replace(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\//i, "").replace(/\/$/, "");
}
```

Comment: This regex does not seem to return a match for anything after the first forward slash following the domain extension .com

Comment: Close but result is displaying /username_here801/ instead of username_here801

Comment: Is there a way to match instead of adding a replace to a partial match?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your getDomain() function to find out where your pathname start.:

```
function getUsername(url){
   var position = getDomain(url).length + 1;
   return url.slice(position); 
}
```